# SQL Melt after Mapping Columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, melt

I have the following working query:

```
SELECT
    postgres."week"  AS "week",
    CASE
          WHEN (postgres."spent_money_office") = 1 THEN (postgres."weight")
          WHEN (postgres."spent_time_office") = 1 THEN (postgres."weight")
          WHEN (postgres."spent_other_office") = 1 THEN (postgres."weight")
          ELSE 0
          END  AS "office_leisure",
    CASE
          WHEN (postgres."spent_money_home") = 1 THEN (postgres."weight")
          WHEN (postgres."spent_time_home") = 1 THEN (postgres."weight")
          WHEN (postgres."spent_other_home") = 1 THEN (postgres."weight")
          ELSE 0
          END  AS "home_leisure",
    CASE
          WHEN (postgres."spent_money_vacation") = 1 THEN (postgres."weight")
          WHEN (postgres."spent_time_vacation") = 1 THEN (postgres."weight")
          WHEN (postgres."spent_other_vacation") = 1 THEN (postgres."weight")
          ELSE 0
          END  AS "vacation_leisure"
FROM
    "lake"."postgres" AS "postgres"
GROUP BY
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
ORDER BY
    1
```

Which gives 4 columns: `week`, `office_leisure`, `home_leisure`, and `vacation_leisure` as shown here:
[image]

I would like to "melt" the leisure columns into one called `leisure_type` taking on 3 values, either office/home/vacation and another column called `weight`. How can this be done using the SQL code query above?

Something like:

| week | leisure_type | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| week 1 | office | 1.78 |
| week 1 | home | 1.78 |
| week 1 | vacation | 1.78 |
| week 1 | office | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a union over the selection of the week, leisure type and leisure value, for each leisure type you have (so three times):

```
SELECT week, 
       'office_leisure'   AS leisure_type,
       office_leisure     AS weight 
FROM tab
UNION
SELECT week, 
       'home_leisure'      AS leisure_type,
       home_leisure        AS weight 
FROM tab
UNION
SELECT week, 
       'vacation_leisure'  AS leisure_type,
       vacation_leisure    AS weight 
FROM tab
```

You can find a fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f4e2ab026c088c961eb1b80d4b4aab57).

Comment: that makes sense, im just not sure how to connect my original query to your part? Cause you're doing the melt straight out of a table, im doing a mapping (coalesce) into a melt so syntax is fooling me

Comment: if you can provide the initial data, I may help you further @guy

Comment: basically `tab` in your example for me is another SQL query that this melt is being applied to, im not sure how to wrap it up together